# Where I can find the stored files in my phone?

Tags: android, file

my app save files in folder Documents. But I can't find this files in my telephone. What the problem?

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir() + DIR_NAME + fileName + ".txt");
                        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
                            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                        }
                    }

                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
                    osw.write(editText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: You are not storing files in folder Documents but in private internal memory. What is DIR_NAME? What is fileName? How did you try to find the file?

Comment: Moreover you should close() the stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
File cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder-name"+"file-name");
//for make the directory if not exist 
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
             //check file and other code...
```

> **android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**
>   is used to check files in phone internal memory.

Comment: This is no answer to the question.